# Akka message is null

Tags: java, error-handling, akka, actor

I playing with Akka framework for Java, version 2.3.9
Everything is going fine, but have issue with callback.
When I run for callback
`getSender().tell(null, self());`

I get in logs

```
[akka://system/user/TowerOfDeath:Current:266:ceil:34] Message is null
    akka.actor.InvalidMessageException: Message is null
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:266)
    at akka.actor.ActorRef.tell(ActorRef.scala:123)
```

It's fine, than I can't send null, made small generic message and problem solved. 
But if that error happens, actor dies. I believe that sometimes possible produce bag, where I will send object, what is now null.

Hot to restore actor in that case?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Supervision, which allows the parent actor to decide how to deal with failures (bugs) like that:

Here's an example: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.14/java/fault-tolerance.html#Creating_a_Supervisor_Strategy

For more information:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.14/general/supervision.html
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.14/java/fault-tolerance.html

Comment: Thanks,
Also I had an issue with supervisor, because created child actors with call, system.acrtorOf, not getContext().actorOf